# How to send Django AllAuth email verification as alias

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth, email-validation

I just setup a Google workspace. One of the accounts has an alias: info@domain.com. I’d like to send all emails from that alias. I know I have to authenticate with the actual account email address through EMAIL_HOST_USER (which I have done), but how do I force Django AllAuth to send emails from the alias email? Is this something that can be achieved by overriding AllAuth views and using send_mail()? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `send_email()` for that all you need to do is pass `from_email` argruament in `send_email()` function.

like this:

```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

You can go through the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/#send-mail

Comment: It talks specifically about configuring the AllAuth django